# How to add user info to S3GetObjectRequest to identify the request

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services

I am new to aws sdk, i have a bunch of S3GetObjectRequest requests added to a operation queue to get the files from s3. I have a situation where i need to check the file downloaded properly or not, if it is not downloaded i have to try it for at least three times to make sure that the file got download. For this firstly i need to identify the request when the complete/fail delegates are called. Does anyone have idea on adding user info to the S3GetObjectRequest request where we can check the file name and number of time the request is created. TIA.

Answer (score 1):

All requests in the AWS SDK for iOS support a `requesttag` property.  Setting this property will allow you to differentiate the requests:

```
getObjectRequest.requestTag = @"your-unique-tag";
getObjectRequest.delegate = YOUR_DELEGATE
[self.s3 getObject:getObjectRequest];
```

Then in your delegate methods:

```
-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError called: %@", error);
    if [request.requestTag isEqualToString:@"your-unique-tag"] {
        // decide to retry or not
    }
}
```